# How to create a Splash screen for VB.net program

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, splash-screen

How do i create a Splash Screen for a vb.net program? I want to make a visual that will come up before the programs starts and after it finishes in this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfkbc5a3(v=VS.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfkbc5a3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Basically you set the form that you want to use as a splash screen in the program properties in Visual Studio. Very simple.

Comment: Work it out...

Press Control+Shift+A (this add a new items) Then go to splash screen, and there you go!

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=swY1mkK-CrY, Youtube clip about it

Comment: @Kuzon: The URL is fixed now :)

Answer (score 9):

1. Open Your vb.net
2. Add new project
3. Go to properties of your form
4. Clear the Text
5. Set the *FormBorderStyle* to None.
6. Insert a background image.
7. Set the background image to stretch.
8. Add a *ProgressBar*, a *Timer* and a *Label* to your form.
9. Go to properties of timer set the *Interval* into *50* and *Enabled* to *true*.
10. Double click the Timer event.
11. Populate This Code Inside The Private Sub Timer_Tick;

    ```
     ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
           If ProgressBar1.value = 100 Then
                  Me.hide() 
                  form2.Show()
           End IF
    ```
12. *Increment* which mean to increase by 1.
13. *form2.show* to show an another form if the *ProgressBar* was done processing.
14. In a Label you must rename it whatever you want.

Comment: Hey, great explanation, but you forget to add the Timer.start at the Form_Load

Answer (score 0):

improvement of other solution
disable Timer before show  other form

```
ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
       If ProgressBar1.value = 100 Then
              Me.hide()
              Timer1.Enabled = False
              form2.Show()
       End IF
```