# Having issues writing the code for this problem in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, splash-screen

[image]

This is the question I'm having difficulty figuring out. I'm unable to get splash screens to show up on my previous two questions I was able to complete the coding and design, but this one is throwing me for a loop.

This is what I have so far

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    label2.Visible = False

    label3.Visible = False
    label4.Visible = False
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Uber")
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Subway")
    comboBox1.Items.Add("Bus")
End Sub

Private Sub comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        label2.Visible = True
        label3.Visible = True
        label4.Visible = True
    End If

    If comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        label2.Visible = True
        label3.Visible = True
        label4.Visible = False
    End If

    If comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        label2.Visible = True
        label3.Visible = True
        label4.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a Splash screen for VB.net program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406522/how-to-create-a-splash-screen-for-vb-net-program)

Comment: SplashScreen video,  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCdaa7N8pHs

Comment: Please rename your controls after you drop them on a form; as it stands your code is meaningless/obfuscated gibberish to anyone wishing to help you

Comment: I just typed "vb.net splash screen" into a search engine and the very first result provided the answer to your question. No one becomes a decent software developer if they can't use a search engine effectively and this wasn't a hard one.